# only one row select at time on UITableView multiple sections. (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)

Tags: ios, uitableview

my english very poor.. sorry TT

only one row select at time on UITableView multiple sections. (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Use thid Sample project [CRMultiRowSelect for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/crmultirowselect) may be helpful for you.